# First time Nodejs issue

Tags: node.js

I am new in Nodejs. I am using Node.js first time. I am trying to integrate a Nodejs API with React.js application. I don't know why this error is coming. My files are like below.

**index.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import auth from "./routes/auth";
const app =  express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:8080/bookworm', { useNewUrlParser: true });
app.use("/api/auth", auth);
app.get('/*',(req,res)=> {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'index.html'));
});
app.listen(8080, ()=> console.log("Running on localhost:8080"));
```

**auth.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import User from '../models/User';

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/", (req,res) => {
    const { credentials } = req.body;
    User.findOne({ email: credentials.email }).then(user => {
        if (user) {

        } else {
            res.status(400).json({errors: { global: "Invalid creadentials"}})
        }
    });
});


export default router;
```

**User.js**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const schema = new mongoose.Schema( 
    { 
        email: { type: String, required: true, lowercase: true, index: true },
        passwordHash: { type: String, required: true }
    }, 
    { timestamps: true }
);

export default mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

I am getting error like below

[image]

What is the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
User.findOne({ email: credentials.email })
.then(user => {
    if(!user){
       res.status(400).send({errors: { global: "Invalid creadentials"}});
    } else {
       res.status(200).send({user});
    }
})
.catch(errors => {
    res.status(400).send({errors: { global: errors.message }});
})
```

According to the error messages, I just added the `catch()` method to handle the promise rejection.

Comment: Thanks @Nguyen. I am getting this error now . https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQf4N.png
Thanks.

Comment: Okay! It looks like that you have to provide `then(){}` block and `catch(){}` block to every function that return a promise. This one return a promise `mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:8080/bookworm', { useNewUrlParser: true })` then we can re-write it like this:

    `mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:8080/bookworm', { 
    useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then( () => console.log('Database connected') )
    .catch(errors => console.log(errors.message) )`

Comment: Avoid using 400 status code for this kind of scenario. In your case you better use `404 (Not Found)` or `401 (Unauthorized)`.

Comment: @Amolpskamble yeah! When writing this answer, I just focus on solving the problem cause by omitted `catch(){}` block and remain all the author's code. Your advides are really good though.

Comment: Thanks @NguyễnThanhTú. Your solution is working. But why I  have to provide `then(){}` block and `catch(){}` block to every function that return a promise. I am following a tutorial on `Youtube`, they are not using this. Thanks.

Comment: I guess they are not using `catch(){}` block because they are confident about their codes which can't go wrong. That's it